# read from database without repeating

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I have a method, which reads from db(it works fine)

```
@Insert
Completable insert(List<Weather> data);
```

for example data.size = 16;

Weather object

```
public class Weather {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public int id;
public String name;
public String description;
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(obj instanceof Weather)) {
        return false;
    }

    return name.equalsIgnoreCase(((Weather) obj).name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 53 * hash + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}
```

in data object look like:
1 London description
2 London description
3 Berlin description
and so on

method in activity

```
public void readData() {
    mCompositeDisposable.add(mDatabase.getWeatherDao().getAllData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .distinct()
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Weather>>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Weather> weathers) {
                    callback.onCompleteRead(weathers);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            }));
}
```

I need , that weathers have not duplicate name 
I add distinct and override equals and hash code in Weather, but it is not work
How can I fix it ? Maybe I wrong override method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one `Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` in the your `Dao` class